# OutofMemory error while writing a large file Android

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to encrypt a large file which is 500MB but my code throws an out of memory error, for small files below 50MB the code works fine. Im using a third party library called [JNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor/JNCryptor) for encryption, please have a look at my code and correct me if any mistake. Thanks in advance.

```
public void encrypt() {
    String file = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/sai/ravi_enc.exe";
    byte[] filedata = null;
    try {
        filedata = IOUtils.toByteArray(new FileInputStream(file));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    JNCryptor cryptor = new AES256JNCryptor();
    String password = "123456789";

    try {
        byte[] ciphertext = cryptor.decryptData(filedata, password.toCharArray());
        String Outfile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/sai/ravi_dec.exe";
        writeFile(ciphertext, Outfile);
        System.out.println("Done");
    } catch (CryptorException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void writeFile(byte[] data, String fileName) throws IOException {
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
    out.write(data);
    out.close();
}
```

Comment: instead of getting complete content in ciphertext , read the file part by part and append into destination files

Comment: @sweeper NO! CodeReview is not an error-checking service

Comment: This library (unknown for me, I don't use) has in api public classes a kind input/output Streams but don't see such use is possible. Like unfinished work????

Comment: We all saw your comment come up and jumped in at roughly the same time.

Answer (score 0):

This is up to JNCryptor to well manage memory, especially if it uses temp buffer. It is better to work on streams instead of buffers. Just for testing, if you write directly the fileData to your outFile, do you get OutOfMemoryError?

```
writeFile(filedata, Outfile);
```